# delta table replication across clouds

Tags: spark-streaming, delta-lake

In my organization we are using AWS and Azure for various data handling tasks.  Data is collected and aggregated in AWS and then is transferred to Azure for BI analytics and reporting.

Incoming data is aggregated daily into delta tables via upserts.  Each table is several dozens of terabytes in size with a couple of billion records each and partitioned in such a way that each partition is several dozens of gigabytes across files optimized for size (with delta's OPTIMIZE command).

Daily updates to these aggregated tables are only a few hundred megabytes each, however a large number of records, easily 50% of a table's records, can be updated on any day.

For various technical and non-technical reasons, we cannot directly use tables in S3 from Azure in the analytics toolchain, so we have to maintain copies of aggregated data in Azure.  Today, we are copying aggregated tables daily in whole from AWS to Azure, incurring significant data extraction costs.

Is there a way to set up replication from AWS to Azure, so that we don't have to keep copying the entire tables?  With something like Spark Streaming I can probably optimize the process where only the affected rows are being copied, but this still means that we would have to copy 50% of rows affected by daily updates.  Still a lot of data.  Since only a few fields are being updated, is there a way to have a process that only copies updated data at the field level?